# Database design: How should I handle product deletion for e-commerce site?

Tags: database-design

I'm sure the delete vs flag debate has been asked to death everywhere but I'm finding it hard to find a satisfactory solution and I feel like I may have left out some issues. I have evaluated the 3 different school of thoughts but I have ran into issues with all of them. Specifically, I am referencing deletion of merchant products/items.

1. Clean delete
   Ensures the cleanest database but also sacrifices data integrity as references are lost. Glaringly, the Orders table will lack critical information about a user's purchase history as normalization rules dictate the OrderItems are stored as a M-M relationship.
2. Creation of some sort of product snapshot on order
   Creating a duplicate of the item for the item flies in the face of unnecessary data and also run into the issue of the degree of granularity - whether to create a snapshot for each order with the basic fields of item name, price, photo or simply move a deleted item to a shadow table on deletion. This method seems to balloon the data storage.
3. Add a datetime field to record the deleted date
   Seems to break the least things but also results in main table becoming very large as some merchants might invariably end up deleting and re-creating the same item multiple times.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: My choice is option 2.  Think of an order as a journal entry.  You want to keep all of the information about an order as the order happened.  You don't have to save images, but you should save all of the order information for a period of time, maybe 5 to 7 years.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc When you say #2, do you mean saving every order information as a separate line item or as a FK reference to a products snapshot table so that multiple similar records are not duplicated? I am already archiving the order price but that would mean I have to archive the product name and description?

Comment: I mean saving every piece of order information in separate order line item and order tables.  It's not duplicate data.  it's a representation of the order.

Comment: That would increase the DB size by close to 100 fold if each item is ordered just 100 times. What is your opinion on storing a snapshot with every product edit?